# Que veut dire « la charge de la première enfance » dans ce texte ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Je travaille sur un texte dans lequel on essaye de montrer que les hommes eux aussi peuvent « engendrer » les enfants grâce à l'initiation masculine vue comme rupture avec le passé maternel de l'enfant. Je voudrais savoir ce que veut dire l'expression « la charge de la première enfance » dans ce contexte (*[Le sexuel et le social. Lecture anthropologique](http://classiques.uqac.ca/contemporains/balandier_georges/sexuel_et_social/sexuel_et_social_texte.html)* de Georges Balandier dans les *Cahiers internationaux de sociologie*, vol. 76, janvier-juin 1984, pp. 5-19):

> Un engendrement masculin métaphorique efface l'engendrement féminin biologique, et social par **la charge de la première enfance**. C'est ce que réalise l'initiation masculine, présentée symboliquement et rituellement comme mort et re-naissance, ou plutôt vraie naissance car l'initié naît socialement. Il meurt à l'enfance, il est séparé de la mère, retiré de la société féminine.

Answer (score 2):

Je penses que **"la charge de la première enfance"** sous-entend :

> **"le fait de devoir s'occuper d'un jeune enfant"**

En aparté, je penses que ce texte se situe en bas à droite de ce graphique fourni par SMBC : [image: science article : a guide]

Answer (score 1):

*La charge de la première enfance* : dans la société traditionnelle, *[la prime enfance](http://www.psychologie.fr/article/la-prime-enfance-A-170.html)* est sous la responsabilité de la mère, c'est donc elle qui en a la charge, historiquement à cause des contraintes de l'allaitement.

*Il meurt à l'enfance*, fait aussi référence ici à la prime enfance : le nourrisson entièrement dépendant de sa mère dans sa vie intra-utérine, fortement dépendant d'elle durant son allaitement et ses premiers pas, va devenir autonome ; ainsi il va abandonner tout ce qui faisait de lui un bébé et donc laisser mourir cette forme d'enfance en lui pour arriver enfant à l'âge de raison (six ou sept ans), puis adolescent...

Answer (score 1):

Tout celà me fait penser au principe du Yin (féminin, créativité, coté gauche) et du Yang (masculin, raison/logique, coté droit).

Un homme, ou en devenir, doit abandonner certainement, non pas l'éducation qu'il a reçu dans son enfance, mais l'aspect où la mère domine dans l'échange en tant que mère dominante. (référence, selon mon raisonnement, à la charge de la première enfance)

En effet, un jeune homme qui souhaite enfanter doit, par là même, décider que sa propre mère n'est plus dominante et que sa femme l'est, notamment dans le cadre de la mise en place d'un nid convenable à l'enfantement.

Voilà ce qui me vient à l'esprit.

Pour me permettre de répondre plus longuement à votre question, il faudraît résumer votre "contexte".

Comment: On écrit "Yin".

Comment: Effectivement, je dois avouer que je fais parfois des fautes d'orthographe.

Comment: Oui il y a quelques fautes, mais le "Yin" m'a interpellé car c'est une erreur souvent commise en toute bonne foi.